# PhantomJS - can't view the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I have my AngularJS app that works on http://localhost:8001

I use that phantomJS script to run and return rendered the HTML:

```
"use strict";
var port, server, service,
    system = require('system'),
    page   = require('webpage').create();

    server = require('webserver').create();

    service = server.listen(port, function (request, response) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));

        page.open('http://localhost:8001' + request.url, function () {
          response.write(page.content);
          var fs = require('fs');
          fs.write('a.txt', page.content, 'w'); //save the output HTML to file
        });
    });

    if (service) {
        console.log('Web server is running');
    } else {
        console.log('Error !');
        phantom.exit();
    }
}
```

so, phantomJS runs on `http://localhost:8002` and makes a redirect to `http://localhost:8001`

when I hit the

```
curl "http://localhost:8002/"
```

I can see the HTML, but I still see the angularJS' `{{}}` tags instead of the desired values. What's more, when I open the `http://localhost:8002/` in the browser, I get the infinite loop. What's going on ?

---

### edit

As my Angular app has the initial animation and sends some requests to the backend, I had to tell the PhantomJS he has to wait
http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2013/07/02/phantomjs-wait-for-it

Comment: This can't be your actual code. `port` is never set.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.